# Antlr error with an empty-possible nonterminal appears twice in an alternative

Tags: python, antlr, grammar

I am using antlr4 python and run into something weird with this simple gammar

```
emptytest   : (COMMA | empty empty nonempty) EOF ;
empty       : SEMICOLON* ;
nonempty    : DOT+ ;
DOT         : '.' ;
SEMICOLON   : ';' ;
COMMA       : ',' ;
```

On input '...', I got error 
    line 1:0 mismatched input '.' expecting {';', ','}

But if I drop one 'empty', or drop 'COMMA |' from the rule, no error.

I am wondering why the input '...' cannot be interpreted as empty (='') empty(='') nonempty(='...') ?

Thanks for any clue.

Answer (score 0):

Your grammar is ambiguous - for input `;.`, the semicolon may be matched either as the first `empty` or the second `empty`.

In such situation, ANTLR tries to resolve the ambiguity by ignoring some alternatives. It seems in this case it resolved the ambiguity by ignoring the possibility of `empty` to contain no occurrences of `SEMICOLON` (i.e. to actually be empty). This applies to all uses of the `empty` rule, so `.` is not considered a valid input.

The takeaway is that if your grammar is ambiguous, you can't expect the parser to behave nicely. ANTLR will warn you about the ambiguity if it encounters one (in version 3 it warns you during parser generation, not sure about v4).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, there is no warning about ambiguity. All I saw is

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, there is no warning about ambiguity, because there is no ambiguity on input '...'.

However, even if it were ambiguous, it seems more reasonable for Antlr to parse it along one of the possibilities, together with a warning, instead of failing on a legitimate input. As a matter fact, the Antlr4 I use does something like that - it picked the first choice on ambiguity: On input ';...', this parse tree was generated.
    (emptytest (empty ;) empty (nonempty . . .) <EOF>)  without warning